# Application firebase Offline

Tags: android, firebase

I am creating an application, I want to add internet permissions in my app I have also added in build.gradle, But my application also opening without internet I want to add firebase like data should be loaded from firebase 
How can I Achieve that ?
Sorry for bad English

Comment: search for a blog how to work with firebase instead of putting this question here.

Comment: Firebase is a platform with many products. If you're asking about the Firebase Realtime/JSON Database, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities. If you're asking about Cloud Firestore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Answer (score 1):

Without context for your use case, it is probably best you look at the docs for [Realtime Database offline support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and [Firestore offline support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

Comment: I have created an news application and there are a lot of images in my application , I have placed it in drawable folder and when I add high dimension Images,application slow down ,

Comment: Should I have to upload that high dimension images on firebase ?

Comment: @HinaSaeed take a look at drawables for different densities, it might help you optimise the images. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html